# ANDROID pre recorded call to a number

Tags: android, android-intent, phone-call

I am working on automated recorded voice calls system. If i use this,

```
Intent callIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL);
callIntent.setData(Uri.parse("tel:123456789"));
startActivity(callIntent);
```

This just makes the audio call. But i want a call to be done to a number with a prerecorded voice message. Can anyone please tell how to do this and oblige

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible in android unless you have a root permission

It locks microphone and will not let anyone access it or morph the input.

Even you cannot record dual voice(Incoming and outgoing) on call

Comment: I dont want to record my calls, but send a recorded message once the user picks the call to whom i have dialed!!

Comment: Even that is not possible as it lets you to tamper actual call